# How to get a live view of vars?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project that involve a lot of information.
My code takes time to run and it is really hard to get a readable output in console.

I would like to have a window that refresh it self while the code is running and show the variables.

Does I have to do it using Qt or is there any easy library that provide such feature ?

Comment: if you want to pause your application as well so you can take some time to read the information you can try out a debugger. PyCharm has one included which works really well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is an IDE that keeps track of variables, histories etc.. Kind of like matlab or Rstudio.

I recommend using Spyder for this.

https://www.spyder-ide.org/

Most people install it through anaconda, although you can just install the IDE for your system python.

Comment: That's what I am using but it's not a live view, I have to pause or quit the program to get the information.

Comment: Ah I see, that's interesting. Never thought about that